# Adding custom data to the node object

Tags: 8, nodes

I have created a content type called providers and when editting said content types users can fill in extra information related to the content.

I have included said form fields using hook_form_alter, and the appropriate hook for _submit applied with it all working fine (saving to db etc)

Where I am stuck is I can access the data, by loading it via hook_ENTITY_TYPE_load call which allows me to access it in _form_alter but for some reason when viewing the node, I do not see the data.

Is there a specific way of loading external data on top of node object in d8?

below is how i load the data.

```
    /**
     * Implements hook_ENTITY_TYPE_load($entities)
     */
    function remittance_providers_node_load(array &$entities) {
      //loop thorough the loaded entities
      foreach ($entities as $key => $entity) {
        // if provider node type is being loaded add our data on top of it.
        if ($entity->bundle() == 'providers') {
          $nid = $entity->id();
          $commission_data = currencyStorage::loadCommission(array("companyID"=>$nid));
          if(count($commission_data)>0){
            foreach ($commission_data as $ckey => $comm) {
              $entities[$key]->commission[$ckey]['amount_from'] = $comm->amount_from;
              $entities[$key]->commission[$ckey]['amount_to'] = $comm->amount_to;
              $entities[$key]->commission[$ckey]['commission'] = $comm->commission;
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
```

I have installed devel and checked all its phases and I dont see it in there.

Comment: Are you printing this data in the template? What do you mean when you say you don't see it?

Comment: yes I am looking to print it out in a template,but when i go to  /devel/node/3 I cannot see the 'commission' data array in the provider entity. In the _form stage i could access the data by doing the following: $node = $form_state->getFormObject()->getEntity(); $node->commission[$i]['amount_from'] etc

Answer (score 0):

I have found preceding value array with [x-default] shows the values.
I presume this has to do with the translation module

```
function remittance_providers_node_load(array &$entities) {
  //loop thorough the loaded entities
  foreach ($entities as $key => $entity) {
    // if provider node type is being loaded add our data on top of it.
    if ($entity->bundle() == 'providers') {
      $nid = $entity->id();
      $commission_data = currencyStorage::loadCommission(array("companyID"=>$nid));
      if(count($commission_data)>0){
        foreach ($commission_data as $ckey => $comm) {
          $entities[$key]->commission['x-default'][$ckey]['amount_from'] = $comm->amount_from;
          $entities[$key]->commission['x-default'][$ckey]['amount_to'] = $comm->amount_to;
          $entities[$key]->commission['x-default'][$ckey]['commission'] = $comm->commission;
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```